Returning a string from a struct in an array gives opcode error
I have a following piece of code:
contract Disp {
    struct Dispute {
        string title;
        string details;
        address defendant;
        address transaction;
        uint256 status;
    }

    Dispute[] public disputes;

    function dispute(string memory title, string memory details, address defendant, address transaction) public returns (uint256) {
        disputes.push(Dispute(title, details, defendant, transaction, 0));
        uint256 id = disputes.length - 1;
        return id;
    }

    function getDispute(uint256 id) public view returns (string memory) {
        return disputes[id].title;
    }
}

I am trying to store all submitted disputes in a global array disputes, and return a dispute title by it's index from the array getDispute
However, when I run the code, create a dispute, and try to retrieve it, I get:
"error": "Failed to decode output: Error: hex data is odd-length (argument=\"value\", value=\"0x0\", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=bytes/5.7.0)"
What am I doing wrong in this code?

I tried this code in remix and it works fine, can you specify how exactly you are running this code and at what point you got this error?

Yeah, I think he might be using an older compiler and evm version.

@Zartaj Afser, I am using pragma 0.8.26 and latest Remix IDE, I get the error when I try to call getDispute function after creating one

just to be sure, you are calling getDispute with the correct index, i.e. 0 would be the correct index if you created only one dispute.

Also, make sure that you use EVM version Cancun, if you’re using 0.8.26 compiler version.

@Zartaj Afser, yes I do just that, everything works fine if I change last function to return not a string attribute of a dispute, but an address attribute(e.g transaction property), then it just returns everything as intended, so this problem only persists with string attributes of the struct
